# overloading operator() for set

Tags: c++, set

Here,in the below code i do not understand why the custom structre has been created and How the overloaded operator() works.It would be a great help for me if someone help me out.
Here in the code i tried to insert the  custom data type in the set.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
   public:
       string name;
    int id;
    Person()
    {

    }
    Person(int id, string name)
    {
        this->id = id;
        this->name = name;
    }
    void print() const
    {
        cout<<"ID : "<<id <<" Name: "<<name<<endl;
    }
    bool operator < (const Person& P) const
    {   ///cout<<this->id<<" "<<P.id<<endl;
        if (this->id > P.id)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    bool operator == (const Person& P) const
    {
        if (this->id == P.id)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

};
struct custom
{
   bool operator () (const Person& left,const Person& right) const
  {
    if(right <  left)
    {
        if (right == left)
            return true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
};



int main()
 {
   set<Person,custom> s;
   s.insert(Person(5,string("G")));
   s.insert(Person(1,string("A")));
   s.insert(Person(1,string("A")));
   s.insert(Person(2,string("B")));
   s.insert(Person(2,string("B")));
   s.insert(Person(3,string("C")));
   s.insert(Person(4,string("D")));
   s.insert(Person(4,string("D")));
   set<Person> :: iterator it = s.begin();
   while(it != s.end())
   {
    it->print();
    it++;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Some recommendations: Don't use `this`, use just the name. Encapsulate your data members, (`name` and `id`) under the `private:` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set<Person>` would use `Person::operator<` to compare objects when adding to the set or searching for an element. `set<Person, custom>` uses `custom::operator()` to compare objects. In this code, `custom::operator()` effectively returns `right < left` (if you read through all the redundant and misleading code), so `set<Person, custom>` creates a set whose order is the opposite of the set created by `set<Person>`.

Note that the body of `Person::operator<(const Person& P)` could be written much more simply as `return id > P.id;`, and the body of `custom::operator()`, as I mentioned above, is simply `right < left`.